# Remove docker image depending on an already removed image

Tags: docker

So, I have been doing something I knew would end up bad, I used the docker rm -f flag to remove an image B because it kept on complaining that another image A was still using it and I didn't find that specific image A, couldn't see it, so I thought, I'll use '-f'.
Unfortunately, of course it did exist, and now I cannot remove image A anymore because I removed its dependency image B and I keep on getting

```
Error response from daemon: No such id <id-of-already-removed-image-with--f-option>
error: failed to remove one or more images
```

when I try to remove it.

So basically, can I remove this image that points to an image that's not present anymore?

Comment: Okay, I just stopped the docker service and removed /var/lib/docker completely. I also pointed it in the /etc/default/docker.io.conf to a nicer folder, because it was filling up my ssd. Silly question, simple answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched off docker through

```
service docker.io stop
```

changed the DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker.io to

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--graph=/home/kasper/dockerrepo"
```

restarted docker through
    service docker.io start
and then removed Var/lib/docker. Didn't figure out a finer grained way of cleaning this up.